# javascript, HTML Form: Click button to insert NULL

Tags: javascript, forms, null

Here is code I am using, which can run in the **textarea** field, but cannot run in the **input** field. How can I modify the code in order can run in the **input** field??

```html
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function insertText(elemID, text)
      {
        var elem = document.getElementById(elemID);
        elem.innerHTML = text;
      }
    </script>
  </head>

    <form>
 <textarea id="txt1" name="passport_no" rows="1" style="width: 100px" required="required"></textarea>
    <input type="button" value="If no value, click here to input NULL !" onclick="insertText('txt1', 'NULL');">
 
 <br><br>
 <textarea id="txt2" name="hkid_no" rows="1" style="width: 100px" required="required"></textarea>  
    <input type="button" value="If no value, click here to input NULL !" onclick="insertText('txt2', 'NULL');"> 

    </form>
```

I tried to modify into **input** field as below, but it cannot run.

```html
    <form>
 <input id="txt1" name="passport_no" style="width: 100px" required="required">
    <input type="button" value="If no value, click here to input NULL !" onclick="insertText('txt1', 'NULL');">
 
 <br><br>
 <input id="txt2" name="hkid_no" style="width: 100px" required="required">
 <input type="button" value="If no value, click here to input NULL !" onclick="insertText('txt2', 'NULL');"> 
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitute `.value` for `.innerHTML` to set `value` property of [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) element

> **value**
>
> The initial value of the control.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function insertText(elemID, text) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(elemID);
    elem.value = text;
  }
</script>

<form>
  <input id="txt1" name="passport_no" style="width: 100px" required="required">
  <input type="button" value="If no value, click here to input NULL !" onclick="insertText('txt1', 'NULL');">

  <br>
  <br>
  <input id="txt2" name="hkid_no" style="width: 100px" required="required">
  <input type="button" value="If no value, click here to input NULL !" onclick="insertText('txt2', 'NULL');">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try by also setting the `value` for the `elem`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function insertText(elemID, text)
      {
        var elem = document.getElementById(elemID);
        elem.innerHTML = text;
        elem.value = text;
      }
    </script>
  </head>

    <form>
    <textarea id="txt1" name="passport_no" rows="1" style="width: 100px" required="required"></textarea>
    <input type="button" value="If no value, click here to input NULL !" onclick="insertText('txt1', 'NULL');">

    <br><br>
    <textarea id="txt2" name="hkid_no" rows="1" style="width: 100px" required="required"></textarea>  
    <input type="button" value="If no value, click here to input NULL !" onclick="insertText('txt2', 'NULL');"> 

    </form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check, is it a Input Tag or Textarea. If it is a textarea, you can use innerHTML function but if it is a Input tag then you need to use .value function. 
 
 
 
Happy Coding! 
  Rz

```js
function insertText(elemID, text) {
     var elem = document.getElementById(elemID);
     console.log(elem.getAttribute("type"));
     // check elem is input or Text area 

     if (elem.tagName == "INPUT" && elem.getAttribute("type") == "text") {
         elem.value = text;
     }

     if (elem.tagName == "TEXTAREA") {
         elem.innerHTML = text;
     }
 }
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" id="txt1" />
    <input type="button" value="If no value, click here to input NULL !" onclick="insertText('txt1', 'NULL');">

    <br><br>
    <textarea id="txt2" name="hkid_no" rows="2" col="3" style="width: 100px" required="required"></textarea>
    <input type="button" value="If no value, click here to input NULL !" onclick="insertText('txt2', 'NULL');">

</form>
```